# Fuel line leak - can't separate disconnect

Tags: fuel-system, cavalier

('04 Cavalier) I have a leak in the (steel) fuel return line, just where it mates with the plastic line from the tank.  I have released the latch on the 'quick' disconnect, and, with effort, I can rotate
the pipe in the disconnect.  But, so far, I haven't been able to pull it out at all.  If anyone knows a trick, I'd very much like to hear it.

Bonus question #1: assuming I can't get the pipe out of the disconnect, can those plastic lines be replaced individually, or are the integrated into the fuel pump assembly, where I'd have to replace the whole tank unit?

Bonus #2: Has anyone ever cut a hole in the floor, to remove the tank unit without dropping the tank?

Bonus #3: The leak is squirting out pretty energetically, like it's under pressure.  This seems odd - should there be pressure in the return line?

Thanks

Comment: I would bet the problem is you haven't pushed the tool far enough into the disconnect to allow it to release. With my tool, the tool "base" has to be flush with the coupler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of your pump assembly. Cost is around $100. There are two lines, I'm assuming one is the return line. If you are replacing the whole thing as a unit, just cut off the plastic end.

[image: 2004 Cavalier fuel pump]

Bonus #1- probably. All the supply and return lines I've worked with go to the pump unit, and the pump unit removes from the top of the tank.

Bonus #2 Yes, but I wouldn't advise it where a gasoline leak is present.

Bonus #3, Yes return lines are low pressure lines, plus there may be a gravity assist. In addition gasoline systems self-pressurize due to the vapor pressure of gasoline.